# typescript: member variables from super class's constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The following code will alert `undefined`

```
class Parent {
    field: string
    constructor() {
       alert(this.field)
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    field = 'child'
}

new Child() #=> undefined
```

whereas, the following alerts 'child' as expected

```
class Parent {
    field: string
    constructor() {
       alert(this.field)
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    field = 'child'
    constructor() {
       // without referencing this.field before super(), this.field stays undefiend
       this.field
       super()
    }

}

new Child() #=> 'child'
```

Is there any ways to accomplish the following conditions?

1. omit the whole Child's constructor declaration like the first example
2. grab the member variable in Child class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jumps to mind is:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(public field: string) {
       alert(this.field)
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
       super('child');
    }

}

new Child() #=> 'child'
```

This doesn't meet your conditions but I feel it is fairly compact.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could defer the property access to a micortask:

```
 class Parent {
   field: string
   constructor() {
     Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        alert(this.field)
     };
   }
 }
```

But while that fullfills your conditions, it is ... still the wrong approach. Pass `field` as a constructor argument, as other answers show.

Comment: woh right, the only option technically meets the conditions, but will stick to the answer above. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to accomplish your conditions, i'm pretty sure.

Grabbing the member variable in sub class happens **after** the base class constructor runs, and calling `super()` must be the first statement in a sub class constructor.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    field = 'child';
}
// the above is equal to:
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){ super(); this.field = 'child'; }
}
```

And this would cause error:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){ 
        this.field = 'child'; // ERROR!
        super(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow typescript playground parsed something like 
```
    function Child() {
        var _this = this;
        _this.field = 'child';
        _this.field;
        _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        return _this;
    }
```

when putting this.field before super()

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20field%3A%20string%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(this.field)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20field%20%3D%20'child'%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.field%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Child()